# Jquery - Ajax: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am receiving the following valid JSON from my server:

```json
[{"name":"Bubble Witch Saga 2","impressions":10749},{"name":"Grinder","impressions":11284},{"name":"Loovoo","impressions":12336},{"name":"Injustice God Among Us","impressions":12786},{"name":"Bookmyshow","impressions":13182},{"name":"Angry Bird","impressions":15404},{"name":"Flipkart","impressions":16856},{"name":"CNN-IBN","impressions":17230},{"name":"Fore Square","impressions":17595},{"name":"NDTV","impressions":19542},{"name":"Whatsapp","impressions":19976}]
```

But I keep getting an error in my console saying "JSON.parse: unexpected character." This is my client-side code:

```js
$.ajax({
    'type': 'get',
    'data': {},
    'dataType': 'json',
    'url': 'dashboard/data/'+type,
    'complete': function(data) {
        var top10Value = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(top10Value, function(key,value){
            console.log(key+" -- "+value);
        });
    }
});
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You dont need to use `JSON.parse` - you have `dataType` set to `json` - and according to JSLint your response is valid

Comment: You'll also want to use the `success` option rather than `complete` to receive response `data`. These 2 events aren't passed the same arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify dataType : json, result is already parsed in jQuery.

Moreover, complete 
function argument is returning an object representing the result not the result itself.

That case you should use `var top10Value = JSON.parse(data.responseText)`;

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is clever enough to parse the response as it is, even if `dataType` isn't specified.

In your case, it is specified and therefore, it is *already* parsed and `data` is the parsed JSON object.

What you are doing is therefore parsing an `Object`.

Doc says:

> **dataType**: (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> **Type**: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the
> server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
> MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
> **JSON will yield a JavaScript object**, in 1.4 script will execute the
> script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available
> types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success
> callback) are:

Comment: It's been twice I read that JQuery automatically parses JSON, but for me it's not the case. How is that?

Answer (score 1):

data returned already json format only,

```
    $.ajax({
       'type': 'get',
       'data': {},
       'dataType': 'json',//Return Json Format
       'url': 'dashboard/data/',
       'complete': function(data) {
           //data returned already json format only
           //var top10Value = JSON.parse(data);
           $.each(top10Value, function(key,value){
               console.log(key+" -- "+value);
           });

       }
   });
```